# Bad padding in McEliece impementation

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to implement the McEliece algorithm and I am having some troubles. When I try to decrypt a message, it shows an exception saying that the ciphertext is invalid. I am using BouncyCastle implementation as a guide for my work. GitHub page of the project: https://github.com/MrOverfl0w/CriptoLab/tree/descifrado

```
// check if padding byte is valid
if (index<0 || mrBytes[index] != 0x01)
{
    throw new InvalidCipherTextException("Bad Padding: invalid ciphertext");
}
```